# Посоветуйте профайлер.

Tags: c, оптимизация

Пишу на С под linux. Встал вопрос оптимизации. Посоветуйте профайлер и что почитать на данную тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так как под Linux, то скорее всего используете gcc, поэтому, думаю для начала можно попробовать встроенные средства - [gprof](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gprof/)

Comment: gcc конечно. Спасибо. Покопаю.

Answer (score 1):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/about.html). У самого честно говоря руки не доходят вникнуть поглубже, но надеюсь у вас это время есть.

Comment: Valgrind - это не совсем профайлер. Да, он может кое-что померить, но основная то его задача - нахождение утечек памяти и ошибок доступа.
Но, используя его, можно посмотреть, кто к примеру выделял много/часто памяти и оптимизировать этот кусок - очень часто это дает хороший прирост.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю задачи профилировщика - помощь в поиске узких мест в коде и дальнейшей их оптимизации. Думаю valgrind может с этим помочь.