# Библиотека json для с++?

Tags: c++, json

Нужна легковесная библиотека json для с++ с возможностью сохранения и загрузки полей типа int и массивов double. Желательно с примерами. Что посоветуете?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

О том что сайт google.com все еще исправно работает я знаю. Интересует Ваше личное субъективное мнение, если Вы работали с чем-то похожим.

Comment: Вопросы из рода " посоветуйте библиотеку" запрещены и подлежат удалению, как и вопросы на счет субьективного мнения.

Comment: @metalurgus, это абсолютно дурацкий запрет (посудите сами, а как еще спросить у спецов, что лучше использовать?)

Comment: Если бы Вам не требовалось сохранение, то посоветовал бы посмотреть на минималистский [Jasmine](http://zserge.com/jsmn.html) (хоть это и не C++).

Comment: Этот запрет абсолютно оправдан. Он вызывает бессмысленные споры. Кроме того, если вам не нравятся правила данного форума - просто не пользуйтесь им.

Comment: А Вы не спорьте и не модерируйте, а лучше квалифицированно помогайте людям.

Comment: @avp, запреты лучше обсуждать на мете. В данный момент подобные вопросы противоречат политике SO, если хотите это изменить - обращайтесь на мету, там и обсудим. А пока такие вопросы должны быть закрыты.

Comment: @ixSci, там подобное обсуждение мало кто увидит.

Comment: @avp, увидит администрация и многие те, кто модерируют ответы, так что мета это самое лучшее место для подобной дискуссии. По крайней мере там можно, что-то поменять. Здесь - нет.

Comment: Господа, а почему еще не закрыты вопросы:

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39763/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/10841/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-linux

http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/69176/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-php

тысячи их

Comment: @ixSci, ну, откройте там такой вопрос еще раз (или он уже был? Тогда поднимите.) / В [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21836133#21836133) тоже можно пообсуждать. / А администрация, наверное, и здесь увидит и вообще в курсе. / С этим конкретным вопросом все понятно -- автора обидели (а зачем?). Про вопросы подобного типа -- т.е. "посоветуйте библиотеки/фреймворки/технику ..." -- я считаю, что большинство из них вполне уместны и неважно, что однозначный ответ невозможен, это в данном сдучае абсолютно не страшно.

Comment: @abalckin, в том-то и дело, что тысячи. Просто фармящие репу их еще не нашли.

Comment: @abalckin, эти вопросы появились до того, как появился ru.SO. Это наследие hashcode. Я не знаю какие там были правила, но на SO подобные вопросы закрываются. Таковы правила.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону: https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Описание и примеры можно посмотреть тут: http://m.habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/254075/

Comment: Действительно, библиотека выглядит привлекательно. / @kala4ek, мне кажется стоит отредактировать ответ и дать  прямую ссылку на нее.

Comment: Спасибо, обновил.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 2):

[jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/)

Простая и удобная, правда кажется не поддержки С++11