# Как создать конфиг. файл для консольного приложения c++

Tags: c++, консоль, config

У меня есть примитивное консольное приложение c++, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы был отдельный конфигурационный файл в котором будут храниться определенные значения, которые в дальнейшем будут записываться в переменные.
Как это сделать ?

Comment: Всё зависит от того чем вы располагаете. Я нахожу очень удобым ф-цию read и writeprivateprofilestring винды - очень легко сделать ini-шку по две строчки (read и write) для каждого параметра ini-файла.

Comment: В чём конкретно у вас проблемы?

Comment: Может есть ещё удобные библиотеки для работы с конфигурационными файлами - xml - требует две либы, одну собственно для работы с xml, и ещё одну для сериализации.

Comment: Да, какого вида файл конфигурации вы хотите? Без этого дальше нет смысла в вопросе. ini, conf (привести пример файла), xml, json, другое?

Comment: нужен файл Ini.

Comment: Есть библиотека libconfuse. Простая как грабли и одстатчоно удобна для простых конфигов

Answer (score 1):

Например используя json. Тут есть описание и примеры как сохранить и прочитать из файла [Библиотека json для с++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426220/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-json-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81)